# Make Startup Disk not working properly

Tags: usb, disk-usage

I can not make startup disk on my USB,it says there is not enough space for this image.
lsblk

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 929,5G  0 part /
└─sda5   8:5    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1   7,5G  0 disk /media/milenko/sdb1
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

There is also red exclmation mark next to my device.How to solve this

Comment: Unmount the USB and try it again.

Comment: @A.B.
Have tried,its the same!

Comment: There should be an Eraser button at the right side of the device name in the lower pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **unetbootin**, `dd` command or the built-in **Disks** utility instead.

#### Using dd command

First unmount the usb device

```
sudo umount /media/milenko/sdb1
```

Then run the following command, replacing `/dev/sdX` with your drive. Do not append a partition number, so do not use something like /dev/sdb**1**

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M; sync
```

Wait for it to write to the device.

#### Using Disks Tool

Choose your device from the left pane and choose the option called **Restore partition image..**

#### UNetbootin

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```